# Como fazer uma progress bar personalizada no android

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, progress-bar

Não comecei a fazer nada ainda, por isso não coloquei código algum aqui, preciso de uma direção do que estudar para fazer uma progress bar no formato de uma caixa d'água e conforme enche ela, uma água vá subindo dentro da caixa... Eu achei um exemplo aqui parecido e irei colar a imagem, queria também saber se é possível a água se mexer.
Segue o exemplo com a água se mexendo porém em web, preciso para android

https://codepen.io/junebug12851/pen/mJZNqN

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você pode utilizar o `lottie` para fazer a animação. https://airbnb.design/lottie/

Comment: Muito legal esse  lottie vou dar uma olhada obrigado